# Wordpress - Consecutive Nested Shortcode Execution Fails Without Line Breaks

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

If I have multiple items nested at the same level, such as a list and a enter it as such into the content of the page:

```
[list]
    [list_item]My Item[/list_item]
    [list_item]My Item[/list_item]
    [list_item]My Item[/list_item]
[/list]
```

It renders fine. If I do the same and format it like this:

```
[list][list_item]My Item[/list_item][list_item]My Item[/list_item][list_item]My Item[/list_item][/list]
```

Every second `list_item` doesn't render properly. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: There is an open ticket for this issue: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10082

Comment: Thanks, just trying to figure out how to get the patch installed... any idea of why this still isn't included in 3.2?

Comment: Done, changed `return '(.?)\[('.$tagregexp.')\b(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/\2\])?(.?)';` to `return '(.?)\[('.$tagregexp.')\b(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/\2\])?([^\[]?)';` in `wp-include/shortcodes.php`. Thanks again!